# Must Build & Reload for roxygen syntax to upload to documentation

Tags: r, roxygen

Everytime I want to see the new documentation generated by adding new `roxygen` comments, instead of just rebuilding the documentation (Ctrl + Shift + D), I have to `Build & Reload` the package for my new additions to show up in the documentation.

When rebuilding the documentation only (Ctrl + Shift + D), I still see the old documentation before my added changes...

I suspect it is a setting that is causing this. What can be the cause and how may it be resolved?

Comment: Did you load_all the package?

Comment: when using load_all after rebuilding the documentation, everything works as it should. Thanks @hadley. May I ask, why is it necessary to load_all to show the new documentation?

Comment: Because we override the default `?` behaviour which doesn't know how to access development documentation.